# За что могли дать +6 репутации?

Tags: поддержка, репутация

Был в отпуске 3 недели, заходил только с планшета. Тогда писать поленился, а сейчас вот вспомнил и решил спросить. В общем, как-то раз увидел "+6" в панели на главной странице. Ткнул в панель, чтобы посмотреть подробности - а там пусто. То есть только старые "+10" к ответам. Что это могло бы быть? 3 раза по 2 за правки? Последний раз у меня было меньше 2К репутации год назад. Вроде никаких незаапрувленных правок не висело. Или это какая-то более сложная комбинация плюсов и минусов?

Comment: А вот не факт, что вообще это на этом сайте искать надо...

Comment: Дали +10, забрали два раза по 2 за удаление вопросов, к которым вы когда-то вносили правки.

Comment: @PashaPash О! Хитро. Вроде все сходится. +10 обычно в таких случаях видно, а -2 - нет, насколько я помню.